# Creating alert messages in Selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Could you please share if we can create a pop alert saying Activity Begins and once the execution of specific scripts ends another pop alert saying Activity Completed.

I tried `Windows.alert which` does not work. Also I have gone through most of the post all are related to handling of pop-ups not related to creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the below one, which gives popup with "HI.." message (example in Java):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.confirm('HI..');");
```

Only thing is you need to use `JavascriptExecutor` to execute javascript which creates an alert popup. Make sure you need to handle this also in automation if required.

Comment: Hi Murali, it is getting errored out with nullpointer exception.. :(

Comment: @vinay, please paste your code and exception so that we can able to help.. I tried answer which I provided and its working fine for me.

Comment: Murali,Sorry it is working as expected i messed up with the syntax...thanks :)